El php no ejecuta en el terminal en visual studio code

No se lo qué pasa es qué al momento de que ejecuté php en visual no me deja y no se porque no carga el php y tengo todo

puedes explicar un poco más de lo que te sucede. Que estas queriendo hacer y que quieres ejecutar. necesitamos más información por favor

Instalaste PHP vía Xampp? Solo agrega la ruta de PHP a PATH de sistema. También hay una respuesta aquí en SOE de cómo hacerlo.

Yo diria que si que funciona, lo que seguramente te está pasando es que ese index.php no está haciendo ni un echo ni un print_r ni nada que genere ningun output que puedas ver en el terminal, así que no te muestra nada de nada. Pon un die("llego); en la primera línea del script a ver si te aparece al ejecutarlo via terminal y así saldrás de dudas. Otro asunto seria que tuviera errores y tengas que ir al log de los errores para verlos, pero ejecutarse se ejecuta tal como aparece en tu imagen.

¿Puedes, al menos, compartir el código de index.php para comprobar si realmente esa es la salida esperada?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
